# How can i select duplicate and dynamic element in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please below same button HTML with the dynamic value I have tried to find but unable to handle this

```
<input data-form="#emailTemplateForm-278" type="button" value="Save" class="btnSave btn btn-default btn-yellow"  
  onclick="$(this).blur();SubmitEmailTemplateForm($(this).data('form'))">

<input data-form="#emailTemplateForm-280" type="button" value="Save" class="btnSave btn btn-default btn-yellow" 
 onclick="$(this).blur();SubmitEmailTemplateForm($(this).data('form'))">
```

I have created below XPath and I want to select the second one

```
//input
  [starts-with(@data-form,'#emailTemplateForm-') and @class='btnSave btn btn-default 
  btn-yellow' and @value='Save' and @type='button'][1]
```

Above one is working fine but this isn't working

```
//input
  [starts-with(@data-form,'#emailTemplateForm-') and @class='btnSave btn btn-default 
  btn-yellow' and @value='Save' and @type='button'][2]
```

Please advice thanks and waiting for your response

Please below same button HTML with the dynamic value I have tried to find but unable to handle this

PFB HTML for Elements

Comment: <input data-form="#emailTemplateForm-278" type="button" value="Save" class="btnSave btn btn-default btn-yellow" onclick="$(this).blur();SubmitEmailTemplateForm($(this).data('form'))">

Comment: <input data-form="#emailTemplateForm-280" type="button" value="Save" class="btnSave btn btn-default btn-yellow" onclick="$(this).blur();SubmitEmailTemplateForm($(this).data('form'))">

Comment: both of your xpath is correct and post the html in question not comment.

Comment: Some One please help

Comment: What is exception if its not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try locators below:

**Css selectors**
 1. button `.btnSave:nth-child(1)`
 2. button `.btnSave:nth-child(2)`

**Xpath**
 1. button `(//input[@value='Save'])[1]`
 2. button `(//input[@value='Save'])[2]`